# C# - How to make a StatusStrip resize a borderless Form

Tags: c#, forms, event-handling, dllimport, statusstrip

I am trying to resize a borderless form with a StatusStrip (I'm using a tool strip for many reasons). I have successfully moved a form with a MenuStrip, but never resized, so I do have a little understanding on sending messages and EventHandling. However, the StatusStrip doesn't move when clicked. Below is what I have so far.

**Custom StatusStrip Class:**

```
public class PassThroughStatusStrip : StatusStrip{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const int HTTRANSPARENT = (-1);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST){
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
        }else{
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

The designer lets me drag-and-drop this element because it recognizes it as a control like I want it to...

**Form Class:**

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{   
    private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void StatusStrip_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left){
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
    private void StatusStrip_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Focused)
        {
            Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I even manually added `StatusStrip_MouseMove` and `StatusStrip_MouseDown` to MyForm.Designer.cs EventHandling through:

```
this.StatusStrip.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.StatusStrip_MouseDown);
this.StatusStrip.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.StatusStrip_MouseMove);
```

But the StatusStrip Still does nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: You made it transparent to the mouse.  Congratulations, that worked.

Comment: How? It's focusing on it when it's not focused and it's sending a message when its clicked. This exact same method works with moving a form, without using a custom one. How is it transparent to the mouse?

Comment: Because you returned HTTRANSPARENT to the hit test of course.  This is a pretty sane thing to do, now you can make the form's WM_NCHITTEST work.  Pretty unclear to me why you'd want to do that with the status strip.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean ill try it out